# Gets google doc worksheet without hidden rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pygsheets

I am actually working on a python code where i want to get as a panda dataframe a google doc worksheet with the "pygsheets" library.
I am just currently doing this:

```
gc = pygsheets.authorize(credentials=credentials)
sh = gc.open_by_key('KEY')
wks = sh.worksheet_by_title('SHEET 1')
df_pd = wks.get_as_df()
```

How can I only get rows that are not hidden in the doc ?

Thank you !